# Problem selecting data from a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Could you help me resolve the issue:

Do You know why `data_OC` is returning 0?. I would like to cell data that have empty DTPE from data_grouped set.

Thank you so much!

```
data <- structure(
  list(Id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
       date1 = c("2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20",
                 "2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20",
                 "2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20",
                 "2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20","2021-06-20"),
       date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-04-02",
                 "2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-03",
                 "2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-08",
                 "2021-04-09","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-04-10"),
       Week= c("Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday",
               "Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Thursday",
               "Thursday","Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday"),
       DTPE = c("Ho","Ho","Ho","Ho","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","Ho","Ho"),
       D1 = c(8,1,9, 3,5,4,7,6,3,8,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3), DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,7,3),
       DR02 = c(2,1,4,3,3,4,1,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3), DR03 = c(7,5,4,3,3,4,1,5,3,3,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,4,3),
       DR04= c(4,5,6,7,3,2,7,4,2,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,4,3),DR05 = c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
                                      

dim_data<-dim(data)

day<-c(seq.Date(from = as.Date(data$date2[1]), by = "days",
                length = dim_data[1]
)) 

data_grouped <- data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date)) %>%
  group_by(date2) %>%
  summarise(Id = first(Id),
            date1 = first(date1),
            Week = first(Week),
            DTPE = first(DTPE),
            D1 = sum(D1)) %>%
  select(Id,date1,date2,Week,DTPE,D1)

data_grouped <- data_grouped %>% mutate(date1=format(date1,"%d/%m/%Y"),
                                    date2=format(date2,"%d/%m/%Y"))
    data_grouped<-data.frame(data_grouped)
  Id      date1      date2     Week DTPE D1
1  1 20/06/2021 02/04/2021   Friday      33
2  1 20/06/2021 03/04/2021 Saturday      22
3  1 20/06/2021 08/04/2021 Thursday      12
4  1 20/06/2021 09/04/2021   Friday       8
5  1 20/06/2021 10/04/2021 Saturday   Ho  5
6  1 20/06/2021 01/07/2021 Thursday   Ho 21

data_OC<-subset(data_grouped,is.na(DTPE))
data_OC
[1] Id    date1 date2 Week  DTPE  D1   
<0 linhas> (ou row.names de comprimento 0)
```

Comment: `from = as.Date(df$date2[1])`... Did you mean `as.Date(data$date2[1])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks for row that are `NA` in column `DTPE`. But, as shown in your data, the "empty" cells of `DTPE` aren't acutally empty but contain an empty string `""`. So either you change `""` into `NA`

```r
library(dplyr)
data_grouped %>% 
  mutate(DTPE = na_if(DTPE, ""))
```

followed by your subset-statement or you subset by

```r
subset(data_grouped, DTPE == "")
```

Since you are using `tidyverse`, you could and should use `filter()` and stay in the pipeline.

Comment: `subset(data_grouped, DTPE == "")` is really the simplest thing to do. Could also do `subset(data_grouped, stringr::str_length(DTPE) == 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the answer provided, you can do one more thing, if you want your existing code to work.

Just add this line, so that the empty cells will be turned into NA

```
data_grouped$DTPE[data_grouped$DTPE==''] <- NA
```

Now, if you run the last two lines of your code, you'll have the desired output

```
data_OC<-subset(data_grouped,is.na(DTPE))
data_OC

Id date1      date2      Week     DTPE     D1
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1     1 20/06/2021 02/04/2021 Friday   NA       33
2     1 20/06/2021 03/04/2021 Saturday NA       22
3     1 20/06/2021 08/04/2021 Thursday NA       12
4     1 20/06/2021 09/04/2021 Friday   NA        8
```